# Получение сгенерированного id после вставки новой записи

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data

Нужно создать новую запись, для генерации id данной записи, создана Sequence (некая процедура) которая и генерирует id на уровне базы.

После вставки записи, я хочу проверить что запись успешно создана и получить ее id.

```
INSERT INTO log_process(log_id, msg_id, code_process, date_rcv) VALUES(gen_log_process_id.nextval, 1096505, 100, sysdate) RETURNING log_id into :pp;
```

такой запрос всего лишь сообщает мне, что запись создана, но как мне вытащить id этой записи, как в Spring Data получить id, только что созданной записи ?

вот как выглядит репозиторий

```
public interface NRepository extends CrudRepository<Nc, Long> {

@Query(value = "INSERT INTO log_process(log_id, msg_id, code_process, date_rcv) VALUES(gen_log_process_id.nextval, 1096505, 100, sysdate) RETURNING log_id into :pp", 
        nativeQuery = true)
  Long insertNewEntry() ;
 }
```

gen_log_process_id.nextval - это процедура для генерации **id**

Кто знает, подскажите решение.

**Обновление**

Спасибо за предложенные решения, но необходимо использовать только Spring data, я лишь указал нужные правила для Hibernate

```
    /**Уникальный идентификатор записи*/
@Id
@SequenceGenerator( name = "jpaSequenceLogProcess", sequenceName = "GEN_LOG_PROCESS_ID", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1 )
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "jpaSequenceLogProcess")
@Column(name = "LOG_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long logId;
```

оно сохраняет запись, я для записи использую встроенный метод из Spring Data

S save (S entity)

Но уже появилась проблема, возвращается значение которое добавлялось, а не то которое реально добавлено.
 Из полученного объекта, правдиво было только сгенирированный id, а вот поля которые заполнялись по умолчанию или поле с датой, которая генерируется автоматически с базой не вернулось так как это записалось в базе.

```
/**Уникальный идентификатор записи*/
@Id
@SequenceGenerator( name = "jpaSequenceLogProcess", sequenceName =      "GEN_LOG_PROCESS_ID", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1 )
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator =    "jpaSequenceLogProcess")
@Column(name = "LOG_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long logId;

@Column(name = "MSG_ID", nullable = false)
private Long msgId;

/**Cтатус сообщения по умолчанию, STATUS=10*/
@Column(name = "CODE_PROCESS", columnDefinition = "int default 10")
private Integer codeProcess;

/*дата генерируется автоматически,с помощью встроенной в базу процедуры,
* для данной таблицы;
*
* Дана и время внесения записи*/
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
@Column(name = "LOG_UPDATED", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Date logUpdated;
```

Вот так получаю последнюю запись из таблицы

```
 String nameTable = "MESSAGES_TABLE";
    String lastEntryQueryFor =
            "select * from (select t.* from " + nameTable + " t order by 1 desc) where rownum = 1";

    @Query(value =lastEntryQueryFor, nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<Message> getLastEntry();
```

Comment: Извините, а зачем вы указали метку oracle, какое она имеет отношение к вашему вопросу?

Comment: _использовался механизм автоматической генерации значений суррогатных ключей , в oracle никогда не работал_ - но если этот механизм никогда не работал, то что вы ожидаете как ответ?

Comment: да потому что для генерации id ( в моем случае) использовался механизм автоматической генерации значений суррогатных ключей , в oracle никогда не работал, для mySql все просто, но для Oracle в моем случае оказалось не так как я ожидал, что вызвало затруднения в понимании поставленной задачи и ее решения........."в oracle никогда не работал"  - опечатка, я не работал в oracle и не знал, что так можно генерировать id, поэтому задал вопрос, так как нужно было найти быстро решение

Comment: S save (S entity) - нужно расширить CrudRepository и переопределить метод save, по полученному id, нужно делать запрос и обратно будет возвращаться уже сформированный объект в базе данных ( не проверял, это лишь предположение)

Comment: Предположение скорее всего верное. Проверте и дайте ответ, если получится. У меня, к сожалению, сейчас нет возможности проверить и чем-то помочь вам.

Answer (score 0):

как то так:

```
create or replace function insert_log_process(
    mg_id in number,
    c_process in number,
    dt_rcv in date 
) return number
is
    pp number;
begin
    insert into log_process(log_id, msg_id, code_process, date_rcv) 
        values(gen_log_process_id.nextval, mg_id, c_process, dt_rcv) 
            returning log_id into pp; 
    return pp;
end insert_log_process;


declare
  l_var number;
begin
  l_var := insert_log_process(1096505, 100, sysdate);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_var);
end;
```

Пример вызова на Java:

```
try {
    CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = CALL insert_log_process(?, ?, ?)}");
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
    cstmt.setInt(2, mg_id);
    cstmt.setInt(3, c_process);
    cstmt.setDate(4, dt_rcv);
    cstmt.executeUpdate();
    int id = cstmt.getInt(1);
}
catch (SQLException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: В ответ на этот код, я получаю в консоли Sql Developer овтет:  Function INSERT_LOG_PROCESS compiled.  Но я в java-коде никак не применю его. Мне нужно возвратить либо id - записи, либо true или false.

Comment: понятно дело Function INSERT_LOG_PROCESS compiled говорит что функция с компилировалась. Да не может такого быть что в Jave нету возможности вызвать функцию из бд.

Comment: Я использую spring data, я и задал вопрос, как это можно сделать, я не утвержадаю, что этого нет

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867348/spring-data-jpa-calling-oracle-function